# How do you set the color of the button using a stylesheet?

Tags: css

How do you set the color of the button using a stylesheet?

Answer (score 5):

Using the `background-color` property to change the background and `color` for the foreground (or 'text' [thanks, DouweM]) -- the same way you colour every other element.

Comment: 'foreground' meaning 'text' ;)